# Белый экран на странице phpinfo(). Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

В админке Битрикса при переходе Настройки-Инструменты-Диагностика-Настройки PHP (`/bitrix/admin/phpinfo.php`) выдаёт пустую страницу. Пробовал на другой "рабочей" странице вывести `phpinfo();` это страница тоже стала отображать белый экран. В чем может быть проблема и как запустить `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Пробуйте в .setting.php дебаг включить. По крайней мере сможете увидеть ошибку

Comment: debug у меня включен. Где смогу увидеть ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел. Дело не в битриксе, а было в файле `php.ini`. Скорее всего в целях безопасности висит функция `disable_function` и в неё включен `phpinfo`. Если убрать из неё `phpinfo`, то срабатывает страница.